# Link keeps directing to the index not the content

Tags: php, yii, controller

I have this messaging feature and every time I click on the actual message, it sends me to the index rather than the actual content of the message.

Here is my controller code:

```
    public function actionViewsent($id,$edge)
    {
        $edge = MessageEdge::model()->findByPk($edge);
        if($edge)
        {
            $main_msg = Messages::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$id));

            $main_message = Messages::model()->getFullMessage($main_msg->id);

            //echo '<pre>';print_r($edge);print_r($main_msg);print_r($files);
            $this->render('viewSent',
                        array(
                            'main_message'=>$main_message,
                        )
                    );
        }
        else Yii::app()->request->redirect(Yii::app()->baseUrl);
    }
```

Here is my model for MessageEdge:

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'sender_id' => 'Sender',
        'sender_name' => 'Sender Name',
        'receiver_id' => 'Receiver',
        'receiver_name' => 'Receiver Name',
        'message_id' => 'Message',
        'status' => 'Status',
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you tell about `$edge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced the:

```
   if($edge)
```

to

```
    if(!$edge)
```

and it worked fine. I hate these mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your condition which checks $edge is false, so it goes to else statement.Try to use some debugging.

```
$edge = MessageEdge::model()->findByPk($edge);
CVardumper::dump($edge,9,TRUE);
Yii::app()->end();
```

in the above code you can dump the $edge to check the value of $edge. So you can find out what is the problem that your condition is always false.

More: please check you $edge value like below:

```
if(!empty($edge) && !is_null($edge))
```

instead of

```
if($edge)
```

It can make you sure that $edge does not hold any value.

I hope It helps.

Comment: Helps, but now I'm getting an error located at the YiiBase.php saying that

  include($className.'.php'); is where the error is stating that this file does not exist. 

Where do you think is a good place to look for this?